# lxml Xml Parsing

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

```
<xml>
<maintag>    
<content> lorem ipsum <strong> dolor sit </strong> and so on </content>
</maintag>
</xml>
```

The xml file that i regularly parse, may have  tag inside of content tag as shown above.

Here how i parse the file:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=False)
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xmlFile), parser)
for item in tree.iter('maintag'):
  my_content = item.find('content').text
  #print my_content
  #output: lorem ipsum
```

as a result it results my_content = '*lorem ipsum*' instead of -which i'd like to see- '*lorem ipsum dolor sit and so on'*

How can i read the content as ' lorem ipsum dolor sit and so on'?

Note: content tag may have another tags instead of strong. And may not have them at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`_Element.text`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#text) property returns only the text before the first subelement.

Try following:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> xmlFile = '''
... <xml>
... <maintag>
... <content> lorem ipsum <strong> dolor sit </strong> and so on </content>
... </maintag>
... </xml>
... '''
>>> parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=False)
>>> tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xmlFile), parser)
>>> for my_content in tree.xpath('maintag/content//text()'):
...       print my_content
...
 lorem ipsum
 dolor sit
 and so on
```

or:

```
>>> for my_content in tree.find('maintag/content').itertext():
...     print my_content
...
 lorem ipsum
 dolor sit
 and so on


>>> ' '.join(tree.find('maintag/content').itertext())
' lorem ipsum   dolor sit   and so on '
>>> ' '.join(t.strip() for t in tree.find('maintag/content').itertext())
'lorem ipsum dolor sit and so on'
```